# python regular expressions basics

Tags: python, regex

I'm experimenting with primitive regular expressions in order to help me find and download files. Accordingly, I was wondering why the following code doesn't work? I understand that re.findall creates an object and I'd imagine this where I went astray. Thanks as always.

```
server_list1=('part002.csv.gz' , '2014-01-28', 'part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28', 'part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')

x=[]

for item in server_list1:

    if re.findall(r'gz', item ) == 1 :

        x.append(item)
```

Comment: findall returns a list of match strings. Please consult the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns an object (as does everything in Python).  However, that object is a list of matches, which will never equal the integer `1`.

---

Since empty lists evaluate to `False` in Python, you can fix the problem by simply doing:

```
if re.findall(r'\.gz$', item):
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> server_list1=('part002.csv.gz' , '2014-01-28', 'part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28', 'part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')
>>> x=[]
>>> for item in server_list1:
...     if re.findall(r'\.gz$', item):
...         x.append(item)
...
>>> x
['part002.csv.gz', 'part001.csv.gz', 'part002.csv.gz']
>>>
```

Also, you will notice that I changed your Regex pattern to `\.gz$` instead of just `gz`.  The new pattern will match `.gz` at the end of the string, instead of `gz` anywhere in the string.

---

However, as @krait mentioned below, you should never use `re.findall` to test if a single string contains a pattern.  Instead, you should use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> import re
>>> server_list1=('part002.csv.gz' , '2014-01-28', 'part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28', 'part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')
>>> x=[]
>>> for item in server_list1:
...     if re.search(r'\.gz$', item):
...         x.append(item)
...
>>> x
['part002.csv.gz', 'part001.csv.gz', 'part002.csv.gz']
>>>
```

---

Or, even better in this case, get rid of Regex altogether and use [`str.endswith`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
>>> server_list1=('part002.csv.gz' , '2014-01-28', 'part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28', 'part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')
>>> x=[]
>>> for item in server_list1:
...     if item.endswith('.gz'):
...         x.append(item)
...
>>> x
['part002.csv.gz', 'part001.csv.gz', 'part002.csv.gz']
>>>
```

Comment: Findall is wasteful in this case, since it must construct a list of strings that are never used.

Comment: if re.search(r'\.gz$', item): returns a true or false depending on what's there?

Comment: @ChaseCB - Actually, it returns a [`re.MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) if it finds the pattern or `None` if it can't.  The former will evaluate to `True` but the latter will evaluate to `False`

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping the `== 1`, like this:

```
for item in server_list1:
    if re.findall(r'gz', item ) :
        x.append(item)

# x => ['part002.csv.gz', 'part001.csv.gz', 'part002.csv.gz']
```

On a side note, your regular expression will match `gz` *anywhere* in the input string. To make sure that the string ends with `gz` use an end anchor (`$`), as in `gz$` or `\.gz$` if you want to make sure it ends in `.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the most pragmatic approach for a given problem. This doesn't need regex matching at all.

```
server_list1 = ('part002.csv.gz' , '2014-01-28', 'part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28', 'part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')

x = []

for item in server_list1:
    if item.endswith('.gz'):
        x.append(item)
```

Or more succinctly:

```
x = filter((lambda item: item.endswith('.gz')), server_list1)
```

Just using the `in` operator, or the regex as you specified (as opposed to `r'\.gz$'`) would incorrectly match `figz.png`, for example.

It also seems like you're storing heterogeneous data in a single tuple. Firstly, I'd recommend you use a list instead, as that's more appropriate for handling a variable number of records. Secondly, make your data uniform: use a list of tuples, like:

```
[('part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-28'), ('part001.csv.gz', '2014-01-28'), ('part002.csv.gz', '2014-01-25')]
```

That way, you can be sure that all filenames belong are stored in the first tuple index, and all dates are stored in the second tuple index. Given `server_list1`, the above structure can be produced with:

```
data = zip(server_list1[::2], server_list1[1::2])
```

Comment: thanks....never have seen the ends with() function. knowledge is power.